# Wormhole time machine and violation of uncertainty?

Tags: experimental-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wormholes, time-travel

Let's asssume we have a wormhole that allows sending info to the past and receiving information from the future.

Next, we have a particle moving in two dimensions, for which we can evaluate $ p_{y} $ and $ x $ at every instant of time.

Also we can receive from the future the values of $ p_{x} $ and $ y$, so we can know without uncertainty the values $ x, p_{x}, y , p_{y} $. It is an apparent violation of uncertainty principle ??, or not ? :)

Answer (score 1):

In quantum mechanics, a system is represented by a wave function. The wavefunction is a sort of blob spread out over $x,p_x$ space and $\delta x, \delta p_x$ represent the size of the blob. At a given time the wavefunction of a system has to be spread out in x if it is highly peaked in $p_x$ and vice versa because $\delta x \delta p_x \geq \hbar$.

The wavefunction may evolve over time so that at $t_1$ x is highly peaked. In this case at $t_1$, $p_x$ will not be highly peaked it will be spread out. At some later time $t_2$, $p_x$ may be be highly peaked in which case x will be spread out. There is no contradiction here since we are talking about two different situations: the situation at $t_1$ and the situation at $t_2$. This doesn't tell you that really the system was at x at $t_2$ or that it really had momentum $p_x$ at $t_1$: it had two different wavefunctions at two different times.

Perhaps you have the common misconception that actually the particle is at some particular point in $x,p_x$ space and the wavefunction just allows you to calculate the probability of the system being in some region by finding the integral of the square amplitude of the wavefunction over that region. There is quite a lot wrong with this idea. For a start the square amplitudes in general *do not* obey the rules of probability, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150.

Second, if it were true that this instrumental procedure was all there was to quantum mechanics then the appropriate thing to do would be to propose models of the underlying physics. This model would not include the wavefunction except as an approximation to the alleged deeper level. There haven't been many serious attempts to do this, i.e. - attempts to come up with theories that totally eliminate the wave function.

Third, any theory that featured only particles localised in particular regions of spacetime would have to be non-local and would have problems with Lorentz invariance too, as illustrated by the experiments proposed by Bell and Lucien Hardy:

http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.68.2981.

Also, there just doesn't seem to be anything to gain by doing this. There is nothing wrong with quantum mechanics that can't be solved by taking it more seriously as an explanation of what the world is actually like. The world really is composed of things that can be represented by wavefunctions, not by particles. there is a large literature on how this explains how this explains what we see around us, e.g.

http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245.

Answer (score -1):

First of all show us how to drill that wormhole, and after that ask your question.
It is a question logically equivalent with what would happen if a car would be a chicken.